# Apache RewriteRule in VirtualHost for directory redirect not working without trailing slash

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, virtualhost, slash

The rewrite url I have is not redirecting if it has no trailing slash.
I want to redirect a user that goes here `http://example.com/po` to here: `http://new.example.com/po/index_mi.php`.

I tried these lines but none of them worked:

```
RewriteRule  /po(/)?$ http://new.example.com/po/index_mat.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/po(/)$ http://new.example.com/po/index_mat.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/po$ http://new.example.com/po/index_mat.php [R=301,L]
```

Here is the full vhost:

```
<VirtualHost 192.228.100.142:80>
ServerAdmin serveradmin@example.com
DocumentRoot /home/drupal_1
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com 
Alias /movies /home/movies/
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/example.com_err_log
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/example.com_log special
<Directory /home/drupal_1>
  Options FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
          AllowOverride All
          DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
</Directory>

# Rewrite Rules #####################
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/webmedia/(.*) / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/marquee.php / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/register /user/register [R=301,L]
RewriteRule  ^/po(/)?$ http://new.example.com/po/index_mat.php [R=301,L]
# end Rewrite Rules #################

</VirtualHost>
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I got it working with this line:

```
RewriteRule ^/po$ http://new.example.com/po/index_mat.php [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash
```

From the [mod_rewrite documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions):

> **AllowNoSlash**
>
> By default, mod_rewrite will ignore URLs that map to a directory on
> disk but lack a trailing slash, in the expectation that the mod_dir
> module will issue the client with a redirect to the canonical URL with
> a trailing slash.
>
> When the `DirectorySlash` directive is set to `off`, the `AllowNoSlash`
> option can be enabled to ensure that rewrite rules are no longer
> ignored. This option makes it possible to apply rewrite rules within
> `.htaccess` files that match the directory without a trailing slash, if
> so desired.
>
> Available in Apache HTTP Server 2.4.0 and later.

Comment: I'm not sure where to place that line in the vhost conf file. I tried putting it under "RewriteEngine On" but it didn't work. thanks

Comment: When I added that line  under "RewriteEngine On" and restarted Apache, it gave me an error RewriteOptions: unknown option 'AllowNoSlash'.
The good news is that I got it working now without it. I'm using this:
RewriteRule ^/po$ http://myothersite.com/po/index_mat.php [R=301,L]
I don't know why it's working now and not before, maybe Apache didn't restart correctly?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^/po$ http://new.example.com/po/index_mat.php [R=301,L]
```

It seems that you must restart Apache or at least do a graceful restart to take effect.